# Smoothness of solutions of the curve shortening flow given bounded curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, mean-curvature-flows

I've been looking at the **Lemma 1.5** of *The Heat Equation Shrinks Embedded Plane Curves to Round Points* ([here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214441371)), where Matthew Grayson proved that

*If $\kappa(s,t)$ is bounded for $t\in[0,t_0)$. Then for some $\varepsilon>0$, $C(t)$ exists and is smooth for $t\in [0,t_0+\varepsilon)$.*

In the proof he uses the formula 
$${\partial\over\partial t}{\partial\over\partial s}={\partial\over\partial s}{\partial\over\partial t}+\kappa^2{\partial\over\partial s}$$
and also
$${\partial\kappa\over\partial t}={\partial^2\kappa\over\partial s^2}+\kappa^3$$
to obtain that
$${\partial\over\partial t}\left({\partial\kappa\over\partial s}\right)={\partial\over\partial s^2}\left({\partial\kappa\over\partial s}\right)+4\kappa^2\left({\partial\kappa\over\partial s}\right).$$
He claims that this equation bounds the rate of growth of ${\partial\kappa\over\partial s}$ to exponential.

Repeated applications of the first formula yield
$${\partial\over\partial t}\left({\partial^n\kappa\over\partial s^n}\right)={\partial\over\partial s^2}\left({\partial^n\kappa\over\partial s^n}\right)+(n+3)\kappa^2\left({\partial^n\kappa\over\partial s^n}\right)\;+\;\text{previously bounded terms},$$
so he gets the same as before for the $n$-th derivative of $\kappa$.

With this, using again the first formula, it is proved that the curve converges as $t\to t_0$. And similarly, $C(t_0)$ is smooth.

He finally applies the Theorem 1.1 to obtain that $C(t)$ exists and is smooth for some further short time.

I'm struggling to understand the key parts of this proof:

- The boundedness of the derivatives is not that obvious to me from the above formulas. I guess he gets an PDE which solution can be bounded by an exponential, but if so I don't really see how.
- From the boundedness of the derivatives of $\kappa$ with respect to $s$ for a fixed $t$, $C(t)$ converges as $t\to t_0$. This is because with $\kappa$ and its derivatives bounded, the curves under the flow must exist for $t\in[0,t_0)$. And the same argument for the smoothness... Am I right?

As you can see I'm kind of lost here, it would be great if anyone could explain to me a little bit these two ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}$
$\newcommand{\pdk}[3]{\frac{\partial^#3#1}{\partial#2^#3}}$
$\newcommand{\pdd}[3]{\frac{\partial^2#1}{\partial#2\ \partial #3}}$

I worked out this proof and I can answer my own question(s) now.

1. For my first question on the exponential boundedness of $\pd\kappa s$, let consider
   $$F(s,t)=e^{\alpha t}\pd\kappa s$$
   and compute its time derivative:
   $$\pd F t=\alpha e^{\alpha t}\pd\kappa s+e^{\alpha t}\pdd\kappa s t.$$
   Substituting the value of $\pdd\kappa s t$ from the equation obtained previously in the proof,
   $$\pd F t= e^{\alpha t}\left(\alpha\pd\kappa s+\pdk\kappa s 3+4\kappa^2\pd\kappa s\right).$$
   We want to put this as much in terms of $F$ (rather than $\kappa$) as is possible. We already know $\pd\kappa s= e^{-\alpha t}F$, and differentiating this gives us expressions for the higher derivatives of $\kappa$ with respect to $s$. Substituting these all into $\pd F t$ we get a parabolic equation for $F$,
   $$\pd F t =\pdk F s 2+(\alpha+4\kappa^2)F.$$
   Since $\kappa$ is bounded we can choose $\alpha$ so that $\alpha+4\kappa^2\leq 0$, so the maximum principle tells us that $F$ achieves its maximum on the parabolic boundary. Then we get

$$\pd\kappa s\leq e^{-\alpha t}\sup_{t=0}F=e^{-\alpha t}\sup_{t=0}\pd\kappa s.$$

2. Once we get bounded all derivatives of $\kappa$ with respect to $s$ (plus the hypothesis of $\kappa$ bounded), we obtain that the curvature and its derivatives don't blow up for times $[0,t_0)$, and therefore the curves under the flow are $\mathcal{C}^\infty$. Hence, $C(t_0)$ exists and is smooth.

Hope this can help others to understand what it is done here, and similar computations that show up a lot in geometric analysis.